# Network speed is dropping while downloading

Tags: linux, networking, router

We’ve got a local network consisting of around 200 PCs located at 2 addresses. All of these PCs are connected to the network via 8 routers, around 30 PCs for each one. All of these PCs are running on Astra Linux (Debian distro).

Once we run, for example, “apt upgrade”, the net speed is rapidly decreasing from 1.5 MB/s to 300-400 KB/s. The same problem for local shared storage, as soon as we are cloning the file from shared directory to local one, things are even worse: it stucks at some point, if file/directory is big enough.

All we know is there are only around 20 PCs are online, downloading nothing.
Routers’ bypass speed is 1 GiB.
Windows hosts are better: there are still speed drops (up to 0 kib/s), but cloning the file doesn’t stuck at some point, recovering speed after a while at the level of 500-3000 kib/s.

I suppose, there is some network problem (not a Linux one), but I’m too weak on networking to locate it.

**Edit 1:** after a while, we figured out, that this problem is somehow related to physical address of PCs. There is no such a problem on address 1. Also, there are no problems on Windows machines on address 2. But Linux machines are still lagging, and it’s not referred to router that these machines are connected to.

Comment: At first glance, that sounds like some major packet loss; does `netstat -s` show a steadily increasing amount of "segments retransmitted" on the source of a copy/download? // 8 routers for 200 hosts sounds like a lot. What kind of routers? How many IP subnets do you have? Are all of those routers just generic "wireless routers" with NAT and all that stuff, or are they dedicated routers like you'd see in a rackmount? Are the hosts wired or wi-fi?

Comment: @u1686_grawity regarding the netstat’s output, I’m able to check it during the day, but not now. // 8 routers are there just because 1 router for each audience (I’m the system admin’s helper at school). Well, may be, I’ve mistaken, and there are only 2 routers for 2 addresses, I don’t know the whole infrastructure properly, due to I had a job recently.

Comment: @u1686_grawity However, there are TP-Link routers as at the rack mount, not as the home ones. As far as I know, there are Wi-Fi hotspots are connected to them, so the Linux hosts are connected via Wi-Fi. But the Windows ones are connected by wire. Also, if I understood my boss properly, there are 2 separate subnets: generic (old) for Windows and a subnet for Linux, both have mask 255.255.0.0.

Comment: @u1686_grawity netstat -s displays around 100-200 retransmitted segments. I guess, it’s kind of fine. As for the problemless machines, it’s 30-40.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be fairly normal... although it's the numbers on the *sending* side, not the receiving side, that ought to be checked. Do you happen to know how the two buildings are connected – fiber, etc.? I'd take a laptop with Ethernet and start plugging it in at various points between A and B to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @u1686_grawity today I’ve realised that it’s even more complex :) it’s connected using a gateway provided by the local government’s provider. As far as I understood, the provider gives IP and subnet, then we deploying a server on a subnet of subnet (?)

Comment: Also, the “gateway” is a huge box located at two addresses. All the traffic goes here, then routing to corresponding address.

Comment: The issue here is there is no way to control this gateway, it’s being controlled by provider.